# Filling an inputbox with a Shadow dom attached

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow

I'm dealing with this piece of html code in a form:

```
<input type="text" class="theme__main-background--background-color--reverse">
#shadow-root (user-agent)
    <div></div>
</input>
```

I would like to fill this input box via javascript, but if I set the value attribute, when I try to submit the form it returns to an empty state.

I think this is due to the shadow attached, am I right? 
If it can help, when I manually fill the input also the child div gets the same text.

Is there a way to fill correctly this field via javascript so that the form can be submitted?

Thank you.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Comment: i am not getting your question .what is your expected result

Comment: I have a form with several text inputs like the one posted above. I would like to fill these and then send the form by clicking on a submit button. I tried setting the value attribute with js; I can see the text correctly inserted in the input field, but as soon as I manually click on another input field the previous filled one returns to a blank state.

Comment: can you expand the shadow dom and tell me what is it inside shadow dom?

Comment: I can see just the div inside the shadow dom.

Comment: if possible can you please share a screenshot of this issue or some sample code with explanation

Comment: or a working fiddle.your above explantion is barely sufficient for providing  a solution

Comment: I made a video if it can help: https://imgur.com/a/oLfngwg

Comment: Perhaps the most useful thing at this point is to see the javascript code that attaches the shadow-root in the first place. That would probably be close to the code that extracts a value from the control. Once done, you should be able to tell how to successfully set it with code. Failing that, perhaps you just set the text content of the div. It'd be the first child of the shadow, which you can get as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot

Comment: Unfortunately the shadow root is closed, so calling shadowRoot on the parent element returns null; I don't think I can directly access the div inside.